# knockout.js button to read a single line in a list of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I would like to implement a button on my page that can read the line where it is and send it in a variable to the contents of this line.

- my table
- description----factor-----dependencies-----button(<-- read only this line)
- description1---factor1----dependencies1----button
- description2---factor2----dependencies2----button

I'm using jquery libraries, knockout, and in particular I am using the SimpleGrid (knockout) to create a view model , but only for convenience (so it is not mandatory).
My initial idea was to create a form for each line and use an instruction that already in the examples of knockout was used.
example : http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html .
Any other suggestions?

> P.S. in my case I modified directly SimpleGrid to add  form at this point

```
templateEngine.addTemplate("ko_simpleGrid_grid", "\
                <table class=\"ko-grid\" cellspacing=\"0\">\
                    <thead>\
                        <tr data-bind=\"foreach: columns\">\
                           <th data-bind=\"text: headerText\"></th>\
                        </tr>\
                    </thead>\
                    <tbody data-bind=\"foreach: itemsOnCurrentPage\">\
                       <tr data-bind=\"foreach: $parent.columns\">\
                           <td data-bind=\"text: typeof rowText == 'function' ? rowText($parent) : $parent[rowText] \"></td>\
                       </tr>\
                    </tbody>\
                </table>");
```

thanks for your attention

Comment: Since you seem to be doing it in loops, you could just pass `$data` on the click, which will be the current row item

Comment: you intend to use an action button that makes for example data-bind = click: $ data.readLine *
(invented)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can access the line viewModel from a button on the line ( http://jsfiddle.net/bG4TK/2/). Is this what you need?

html:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
       <!--ko foreach:lines -->
       <tr>
           <td><input data-bind="value:description" /></td>
           <td><input data-bind="value:factor" /></td>
           <td><input data-bind="value:dependencies"/></td>
           <td><button data-bind="click:sendStuff">send</button></td>
       </tr>   
       <!--/ko-->
    </tbody>
</table>
<button data-bind="click:addLine">add line</button>
```

js:

```
var Line = function(description, factor, dependencies){
    var self = this;
    self.description = ko.observable(description);
    self.factor = ko.observable(factor);
    self.dependencies = ko.observable(dependencies);
    self.sendStuff = function(){
        alert("I'm sending the line: " + self.description() + " " + self.factor() + " " + self.dependencies());
    }
}

var VM = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.lines = ko.observableArray([
        new Line("descr1", "factor1", "deps1"),
        new Line("descr2", "factor2", "deps2"),
        new Line("descr3", "factor3", "deps3"),
        ]);
        self.addLine = function(){
            self.lines.push(new Line("newDescr", "newFactor", "newDeps"))
        }
}

 ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

Comment: OK, so what do you need?

Comment: oh sorry, I was confusing post